# How to pass variables from javascript to form?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, google-maps

In my application I get json with place details from google maps API using autocomplete

```
var place = autocomplete.getPlace();
```

I can get a name of the place with `place.name`
On the same page I have a form where I get another details from user. The question is how do I pass the `place.name` to my rails controller when the form gets submitted? In js I tried to change HTML of the form

```
<form...>
<div id="hidden_fields"></div>
</form>
```

using

```
$("#hidden_fields").append("<input name='name' type='hidden' value='"+place.name+"' />");
```

But apparently it doesn't works. 
Should I learn AJAX to do such things or there another ways?
Thanks in advance for any hint.

Comment: Do they appear in the HTML correctly? Perhaps try double quotes for the HTML attributes `type="hidden"`

Comment: $("#hidden_fields").append("<input name='name' type='hidden' value='"+place.name+"' />"); don't add nothing into html, which is strange, because $("#hidden_fields").append("<h1>I'm hidden</h1>"); does appear as it should

Comment: Have you tried looking at it with Firebug or similar? (something that will show dynamic DOM entries)

Answer (score 0):

Please ensure you are creating the hidden fields after the autocomplete finished. check the viewsource if the hidden variables has appended before submitting. As long as the control available with in the form tag before submit, your controller able to get it.

Comment: `View/Source` will never show dynamically added content.  You would have to look in a DOM inspector.

Comment: Please see my answer to Martin Lyne

Comment: OK, firebug can see it <input type="hidden" value="" name="name"> Value is empty but apparently this is another problem

Comment: @user1798125  which means the binding happening before autocomplition. Try to do the binding after completing the autocompletion.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you all! The problem has been solved. The important things I learned were

1. View/Source doesn't show dynamically added content, but Firebug does.
2. Rails modify forms field names: It turns

<%=form_for @place do |f| ...

<%= f.password_field :password , :class =>"form-field", :id =>"passwordField"

into

`<input class="form-field" id="passwordField" name="place[password]" type="password" />`

which means that I have to pass values from js in the same manner:

`$text.append('<input name="place[name]" type="hidden" value="'+place.name+'"/>');`

Hope it will help to someone else.